# C++ : Find the closest values in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

i'm looking for a beautiful way to search in an array the two closest values and return the difference between them.

ex:
if i give these numbers:
10,1,43,59,78,46,63,12

he has to find 10/12, 43/45 and return 2.

I found many way yo find the closest value to a given number but never found a way to just found the two closest numbers without a given number.

i try to use  for being more effective but it didn't worked every time for me, is someone have an idea ?

my code is that for the moment:

```
set<int> numbers;
//imagine i set many values in numbers here
int diff = 100000000;
for (set<int>::iterator it=numbers.begin(); it!=numbers.end();) 
{
    int first = *it;
    int second = *(++it);
    diff = min(abs(second-first), diff_min);
}
cout << diff << endl;
```

Thx.

Comment: Sort the numbers and then do a pass, checking numbers in consecutive positions.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It sure is elegant, but efficiency-wise, it is still `O(n lg n)`, the same as OP's code. Also, putting them in a `std::set` and accessing them using an iterator already makes it act as a "sorted array". That is what the OP is doing,

Comment: Sort the array, and iterate through the sorted array, checking pairs of numbers.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. When it points to the last element in numbers, `++it `addresses no element, and `*(++it)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no other way than to do a brute force ?

Comment: I don't consider O(n log n) to be brute force here.  Checking all pairs in O(n^2) time would be brute force.  Also, @Lingxi is right -- your code has a bug.  Finally, you don't need the `abs()` call, since a `std::set` always returns elements in nondecreasing order.

Comment: For large sets of simple numbers, radix sort (which has complexity O(N)) is very efficient and will give you a total complexity of O(N). The only issue is space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables can be used but it will increase space complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested with its scalability, there is an O(N) method (or closer to in anyway) for your task... It's based on *binning* the numbers and then search for the shortest distances only considering close bins.

I will elaborate further later if interested.

Comment: Conceptually, this must be similar to using a radix sort (which is O(N)) plus comparing; except, perhaps, that radix sort is hierarchical and hence more efficient.